# Basic Understanding of Server Interaction with Mobile Client - Node.JS, Express, BAAS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, ionic-framework

I've completed a couple of MEAN stack tutorials in hopes of creating a backend for a mobile app. In these tutorials, the front-end is included in the file structure of the Express Application.

1. For a mobile app (I'm developing with the Ionic framework), I'm guessing that I would take out all front-end code, and deploy the Express/Node.js app to the server, so it can answer all requests (from these mobile clients)? In this way, it differs from the tutorials I've been following?
2. I'm curious as to what recommended practice would be for a novice programmer in building a prototype. Would it be best to go with a BAAS? It's been hard for me to understand what best approach to take, and whether Express with MongoDB is a great way to go. Requirements are:

   - Upload photos
   - Description for photos
   - Like and unlike pictures

I've only been programming for a couple months, just curious what those with experience would think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an API for the server side,
and for the client side , you need to make API calls from it. 
check out this [article](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/backend-data/)